# Unable to get product custom attribute value on product page

Tags: magento, attributes, product

I introduced an attribute for products from admin, and assigned a value to it for a specific product to get it's value. But the value is not showing up on frontend, I tried all recommended methods but was unable to get it. Then I moved on it's debugging with `print_r($_product->debug())`. And this debug showed me the following behavior:

```
Array
(
    [store_id] => 1
    [entity_id] => 339

    [_cache_instance_products] => Array
    (
        [0 (Mage_Catalog_Model_Product)] => Array
        .
        .
        .
        [419 (Mage_Catalog_Model_Product)] => Array
        (
            [entity_id] => 1210
        [entity_type_id] => 4
            [prd_help_tab] => This is testing help for "Mobster US e-liquid"
        )
    )
)
```

The attribute name is "prd_help_tab" and  it's value is there, but it's inside _cache_instance_products => 419 (Mage_Catalog_Model_Product) => prd_help_tab

My question is how to get this value in template file? As the value is only in hierarchy which mentioned above.

After further investigations, I came to know that this problem raises up in "Configurable Products".

Comment: I'm having the same issue, did you end up finding a solution?
I wrote my question here:  http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/144982/41099

Comment: @Pitt I'm not sure as the question was raised around 3 years ago but I think for this I would've created another database lookup query, to manually get it.

Comment: thanks for your quick answer! I'll have to look into it further.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to

```
$_product->getPrdHelpTab();
```

Try adding to the product collection when it's gathered

```
$_productCollection->addAttributeToSelect("prd_help_tab");
```

Make sure the attribute in the admin is included in flat tables by setting it to "Used in Product Listing" and then reindexing

[image: include attribute in product flat]

Comment: Actually, I've already checked those all options. And tried a lot of many other solutions but still unable to get the value. About $_productCollection->addAttributeToSelect("prd_help_tab"); I'm not sure coz I'm displaying the tab in product page not product listing. What I'm doing is as follows: <?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); echo $_product->getPrdHelpTab();?> But cannot see anything. I've also tried all other combinations e.g. $_product->getData('prd_help_tab') and more... But nothing is working.

Answer (score 0):

First:
make sure the attribute in admin config is set as visible in catalog list and product view layout.

Simple:
Magento have hierarchy to call the values by the name, but on the page MUST have load Magento library and product helper for the right product (by your debug you have it) $_product = $this->getProduct();

Call for your value should look like: $_product->getPrdHelpTab();

OR, if not work call:

```
<?php
    $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
    $_product = $this->getProduct()
?>
<?php if($_additional = $this->getAdditionalData()): ?>
<?php foreach ($_additional as $_data): ?>
<?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?>
<?php endforeach;?>
<script type="text/javascript">decorateTable('product-attribute-specs-table')</script> 
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('custom attribute'); ?></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi just write your attribute code at the place of custom_pro_name in for display value in view.phtml product page.

```
<?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, nl2br($_product->getcustom_pro_name()), 'custom_pro_name')
```

If you have group product then write this code in group.phtml page

```
$this->escapeHtml($_item->getfirst_avail())
```